# Backup of Files Beyond Compare

Tags: beyondcompare

How to get the backup of files before you Copy and Save? 
This didn't show the changes of all the files that I changed in the Source File when compared with the Destination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond Compare's Options dialog has a "Backups" page that allows you to turn on backups before copies and saves using various different renaming methods.